# Can you share Lunch boxes between vaults?

Tags: fallout-shelter

If you get/buy a lunchbox in one vault can you open it in another?

(Yes I could test this myself but it only just occurred to me and I've left my iPad at home so that I won't play the game at work :) )

Comment: Because the beginning quests are so easy, and give lunchboxes, this would make it far too easy to stock up on lunchboxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168521-fallout-shelter/72056368), you can't :

> 8. Can I trade resources/items/dwellers between vaults on my device?
>
>    You cannot trade between the Vaults, they are totally separate.